# MySQL clean up HAVING with WHERE or JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, having

I have a query that gets all Documents when it has Attempts with NO status of 2 or 3 AND that are older than 7 days:

```
SELECT D.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(A.status) as statuses, 
MAX(A.datetime) as maxDate FROM documents D

LEFT JOIN attempts A on A.documentId = D.id

GROUP BY D.id

HAVING statuses NOT LIKE '%2%' 
AND statuses NOT LIKE '%3%'
AND DATE(maxDate) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

I am grouping A.status into statuses and checking for 2's and 3's, then checking the MAX date to see if it's 7 days old.

But, I have heard that using HAVING is not the best way of doing this and that my LIKE is a very bad idea. Does anyone know if this is true or if there is a better way to optimize this code? I have been at this for a few days now and this seems to be the fastest method (tried subqueries and a few other methods).

EDIT: To explain the structure a little better, A Document can contain an unlimited number of Attempts. Attempts connect to the id of the document using documentId.

Comment: I think the problem could be solved by modifying how you join the tables.  Could you give some information on the structure of the attempts table?

Comment: Just to clarify:
No status 2,3 AND older than 7 days= status 2,3 allowed when document is just 6 days old?

Comment: All three conditions must be met: there can never be a 2 or 3 and the date must always be older than 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query is more efficient than the original. `LIKE` is a very inefficient operation because it loops through each character looking for 2 or 3; it is much more efficient to look for an exact match, even if this does require a subquery.

An alternative way of writing the remaining condition in the `HAVING` clause is by using a subquery, but this will be more inefficient than just using `HAVING` in this case as a subquery is a separate query that has to be executed for every row in the main query. The `HAVING` clause is simply a condition that gets checked for each value that we are grouping by.

This will require you to have a primary key for the table `attempts`; I called it `attempt_id`.

```
SELECT D.*, 
MAX(A.datetime) as maxDate
FROM documents D
LEFT JOIN attempts A on A.documentId = D.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT status
                    FROM attempts A2
                   WHERE A2.attempt_id = A.attempt_id
                     AND A2.status = 2
                      OR A2.status = 3)
GROUP BY D.id
HAVING DATE(maxDate) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```